# Theme preview fails in Eclipse

Tags: android, android-theme

I have made a simple username/password dialog to which I want to apply a theme (it basically defines `windowBackground`) and would also like to preview in `Eclipse`.

I see that my theme is displayed along other themes in the Theme combo box, but selecting it produces the following error:

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?
Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Couldn't find theme resource attr/textAppearanceLarge for the current theme
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
```

Theme definition:

```xml
<style name="my_theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/form_header</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Debugging works fine. However WYSIWYG would be more appreciable.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050443/android-development-missing-theme-error-in-eclipse-ide-for-layout-xml-files

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Close your layout files in the editor **first** and restart your Eclipse.

Comment: You should choose the correct customized theme from the top select list of graphical layout view.

Comment: Note that in case of an eclipse error (with the markup being fine), only restarting in itself does NOT help, but you will have to **close the xml file** before restarting eclipse (just as Sibevin Wang says btw).

Comment: This worked on AS too. Needed to close the layout xml file first.

Comment: My xml did not have any errors and my styles are corrects. After restarting  it turned well

Answer (score 24):

I also got this problem.
I solved it by changing theme.
Steps to do this

1. Open activity in "Graphic Layout"
2. Click drop down list AppTheme (On top bar of activity "Graphic Layout")
3. Select Project Themes->AppBaseTheme

Answer (score 5):

You should choose another theme in Graphic Layout (ex: default theme). I think your custom theme not support some attribute.

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure your all other styles.xml present under different values contains your custom theme part.**

I had similar problem. 
In my case I had added a custom theme in values-large folder under res. And it was working at runtime but giving error as yours in eclipse. 
So i tried adding the custom part(in my case totally there was 3 tags added to styles.xml file) in all other styles.xml file. i.e. styles.xml files under `values-normal-hdpi`, `values-normal-mdpi`, `valuse-v11` and `values-v14`...

And BOOM!!! It solved my problem which wasted my whole day.