# Unable to change the package name in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to update the package name of the application but unfortunately I got an error.Any reason why  this occurred ?.I renamed it by using the android tool->rename application package

[image]

Comment: Just clean your project. It may solve your problem

Comment: Did you change the package of manifest and .java classes?

Comment: First change in the manifest and then rename the packages

Comment: @RajeshM If i change the package name then all the  reference has to be changed,

Comment: try to replace your older package with new using file search.

Comment: @Abhilash go with what Haresh said, i hope that will solve your problem .

Comment: Either you did not rename the application package correctly or you did not change its each and every instance in your project. Also you have to update your launch configurations in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

Close your layout files in the editor and restart your Eclipse.
 [[Theme preview fails in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301171/theme-preview-fails-in-eclipse][1])