# Adding another line of components to relativelayout

Tags: java, android, layout, button

Anyone know how to get this result?

[image]

***Description:***
When the '+' button is clicked, another line of *EditText*, *Spinner*, *EditText* and *Button* will be displayed below the line. And lines go on adding if the user click on the '+' button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best would be to implement a custom `ViewGroup` extending a `LinearLayout` in vertical orientation.

You'll register an `OnClickListener` on the last button: if the row is the last in the list, you'll inflate a new `ingredients_item.xml` and add it to your view (also you'll refresh the drawable from `+` to `-`), otherwise remove the current row.

Your custom view will provide a method like `List<Ingredient> getIngredients()`, so you'll be able to pass this list to some `save()` method.

[image: screenshot]

I pushed the demo [on GitHub](https://github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/ingredients)

Comment: Thanks for the respond. Is there any other simple way? Or can you explain in more simpler way? As I am very new to android. Thanks =)

Comment: It's not that difficult. I'm setting up a demo

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot! But I still have one question.`Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?` is shown when I open the ingredients_items.xml How can I solve that?

Comment: It seems [an Eclipse issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5050443/315306), not really sure why. Anyway, that's just a demo project, so even if you can't run it, you can still browse the code, or at least cut 'n' paste it