# Java Eclipse android-XML editor (graphic display) is not working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm developing some apps for Android on Java Eclipse. As for now everything was ok, but today suddenly the layout graphic display stopped working, no matter if I try to create new layout or try to open existing one. It shows *No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document.* error. I tried to follow [android sdk main.out.xml parsing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393103/android-sdk-main-out-xml-parsing-error) instructions, but I have no *XSL* option in
*Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Lauch Configuration -> Filter checked launch configuration types*. I also don't have any .out.xml file.

Here's my XML and manifest file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".FirstScreenActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="s.manipulator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FirstScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_screen" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="android.app.LauncherActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="s.manipulator.FirstScreenActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy fix:

Right click on the layout file -> Open With -> Android Layout Editor

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations and select *.xml and then press Default on the Android Layout Editor entry in the list of associated editors.

Comment: Unfortunatley, no effect. It was just as if this Graphic Display in Layout Editor was not working properly (it showed no contend while there was actual content in raw XML code).
After some further research [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050443/android-development-missing-theme-error-in-eclipse-ide-for-layout-xml-files) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992036/graphical-layout-missing-for-layout-xml-files), I ended up reinstalling ADT Plugin, which solved the problem, but still, it is kind of a poor solution...

Answer (score 0):

What I had to end up doing was selecting the `Legacy Android Xml Resources Editor` from the same list that kumar_android is referring to and setting it as the default.  I had to choose it from the list that appears when you click the add button.  After that I restarted eclipse and everything was fine.